# Dynamically unload / load section (DOM) of a page

Tags: html, dom

**Problem**:

We have built a dashboard-like application where users can add views dynamically (think of it like Tabs). As the users load more number of views, the page keeps crashing. This could be because of the heavy DOM count & lots of listeners on the page.

**Solution**:

We are looking for a way where we can intelligently unload a tab (DOM & its listeners) and reload it back when the user goes back to the tab. The tab should be unloaded and persisted in some form (some HTML5 client storage) so that we can get it back to the same state. Do we have any libraries to do this?

Serialize data and its state: One approach we are considering is to serialize the data and its state in localstorage and try to reconstruct the view based on the data. This approach should work and if we are using frameworks like Angular, it could be relatively easy. Pros: Separate views & data rendering logic. Cons: The solution is not generic.

We are looking for something which works at DOM level.

Comment: page crash means something in browser or you have tried something different then browser ?

Comment: Page doesn't crash always. But, gets real heavy as we add more tabs. Hence, trying to offload some DOM till the user goes back to that tab.

Comment: I thing you need to improve your code. If you like you can limit how much tab can be open at single time. IF you use caching for javascript object and use them again then it save some cost of memory In JS.

Comment: I don't want to put a limit on number of tabs. I am looking for a solution where the application can intelligently unload some of the tabs and reload it back on demand.

Answer (score 0):

You could try caching just the model instead of the entire DOM. JS generation of DOM isn't as slow as you think.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the entire tab and all the listeners you should make a JSON with the important values of the tab that you pretend to unload, then you can just remove the tab.

If the user wants to open it again, you can load an empty tab, then use the values you saved to restore the previous tab state. This way you don't need any extra libraries.